# Is there a way to see if window.top is accessible?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe that tries to call a function in the parent window, like so:

```
window.top.updateIFrame(height);
```

Obviously, this will only work if the the iframe and the parent window location are on the same domain. So I want to check to make sure that window.top is accessible before trying to call the function. But I can't seem to accomplish this.

I've tried setting window.top to an object, and the object exists, but I can't figure out a way to see if access is denied or not.

Comment: Would a `try/catch` work here?

Comment: you can't just do if ( window.top && window.top.updateIFrame){} ? you can aways jsut wrap it in a try Catch

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's what I'm doing now.  But I would like to check first

Comment: @theporchrat, no Because window.top is an object and will return true.  But, window.top.updateIFrame will cause an exception in the conditional

Comment: I'd suggest looking into [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).  It lets you send messages between iframe and parent, even if they are on different domains!  So, instead of calling `window.top.updateIFrame`, you do `window.top.postMessage`, send it the height, and the parent can then call `updateIFrame` for you. :-)

Comment: We used postmessage initially, I can't remember why we had to scrap it.  But we had issues, I think it may have been cross browser compatibility.

Comment: @Smeegs: `postMessage` should work in all modern browsers.  Heck, it even works in IE8, though I think you can only send strings, whereas other browsers will let you send objects.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but like I said, we had to abandon that method.  I can't remember why.

Comment: @Smeegs: That's the only suggestion I can give.  I use it in my project and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try/catch:

```
    function checkIfTopIsAccessible(){
        let windowVariable = null;
        try{
            windowVariable = top.window.document;
        }catch(e){
            // some log or even empty
        }
        return windowVariable;
    }
   
    if(checkIfTopIsAccessible() === null) return;
```

Also with the function below you can try to save the top.window reference:

```
    function getWindowReference(window) {
        /*
        window.frameElement === null in two cases:
            1. if the window isn't embedded into another document => window === top.window
            2. if the window is on a diffrent origin (from the top.window) => window of the safe iframe window
        so the window.frameElement has a value when it is embedded into another document on the same orgin => return top.window
        */
        if (window.frameElement === null) {
            return window;
        } else {
            return top.window;
        }
    }

    const windowVariable = getWindowReference(window);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use checking

```
if (typeof(window.top) == 'object' && typeof(window.top.updateIFrame) == 'function') 
   ...
```

Comment: `typeof(window.top) == 'object'` will always return true for the iframe regardless of domain.  The object exists, but access to the object properties/methods are denied.

Comment: No, this won't help.  `window.top.updateIFrame` is a function, it just can't be called due to security.  It'll throw an exception when called.